# Axiom of union; union of natural and real numbers

Tags: elementary-set-theory

In set theory we assume the axiom of union to be true for all universes, more formally $\forall x \exists y \forall [z \in y \Leftrightarrow \exists t (t \in x \land z \in t)]$. We call the set $y$ the union of $x$.

This is intuitively understood as the set consisting of the elements of the elements of $x$, but I have trouble understanding the scenario where the elements of $x$ aren't generally considered to be sets.

Take the natural numbers $\mathbb{N}$ as an example. After the axiom $\cup \mathbb{N}$ exists and it consists of the elements of the natural numbers; however, numbers aren't intrinsically sets. As everything has to be a set in set theory many different set theoretic constructions of our number systems have been devised, such as the Von Neumann construction of the natural numbers.

What I'm wondering is what $\cup \mathbb{N}$ or $\cup \mathbb{R}$ in fact are, especially in the usual set theoretic constructions. Do they have some kind of a deeper property or are they arbitrarily determined by the universe $\mathscr{U}$ and the construction of $\mathbb{N}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ in $\mathscr{U}$?

Comment: "Numbers aren't intrinsically sets": see https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set-theoretic_definition_of_natural_numbers

Comment: What I mean is that numbers aren't intuitively considered as sets, but rather an artificial set theoretic construction is devised to incorporate numbers into set theoretic language. The number 1 is still the number one whether it is represented by the set {} or the set {{}, {{}}}. Of course one could argue that the number 1 is per se its set theoretic representation but that would drift off to a philosophical conversation.

Comment: This is not about intuition. It's about axioms. You're not intuitively thinking about yourself as a sum of atoms. But are you?

Comment: Yes, but regardless of how you construct the natural numbers using sets it is true that $3$ divides $6$. The property of divisibility isn't tied to the sets.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the usual set-theoretic construction of $\mathbb{N}$, in which $0 = \{\}$ and $n+1 = n \cup \{n\}$, you have
$$
\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}=\{\{\},\{0\},\{0,1\},\{0,1,2\},\ldots\},
$$
and so 
$$
\bigcup\mathbb{N}=\{0,1,2,3,\ldots\}=\mathbb{N}.
$$
There's not a comparably simple construction of $\mathbb{R}$ in ZFC, so I think $\bigcup\mathbb{R}$, while it must exist, will depend heavily on the details.  For instance, there are at least two different constructions in which the elements of $\mathbb{R}$ are equivalence classes (subsets) of another set: the set of Cauchy sequences in one case, and the set of Dedekind cuts in the other.  Using these constructions, $\bigcup\mathbb{R}$ is either the set of the Cauchy sequences or the set of Dedekind cuts, which are clearly quite different.

Indeed, even $\bigcup\mathbb{N}=\mathbb{N}$, while elegant, isn't necessary.  Other constructions of $\mathbb{N}$ include representing its elements as collections of finite subsets of some other infinite set $A$.  (I.e., "3" is the set of all 3-element subsets of $A$, "4" is the set of all 4-element subsets, etc.)  In this case, $\bigcup\mathbb{N}$ would be the set of all finite subsets of $A$.